# How to prevent emails from failing when a bounce-back occurs

Tags: process-builder, apex-email-service

If an email is sent out by Salesforce to a dead email address in a batch of email addresses, the process should continue for remaining email addresses instead of terminating the process upon failure/bounce-back.
how we can do it in optimize way

Comment: Updated your title to match what you're actually asking.

Answer (score 2):

I think this would depend on how your sending out your batch email.

### APEX

If you're sending via apex there is a flag you can use.

The send method prototype [from the docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_messaging.htm):

```
sendEmail(emails, allOrNothing)
```

If you set the allOrNothing flag to false, you should be able to keep sending even if some of the emails fail.

### Any other way

You'll have to give us more information if you want any help other than APEX

Answer (score 0):

Basically there is no such a utility/function/field in Process Builder or Workflow that would allow to check it in runtime if an email was bounced on not. Moreover, if your process in Process builder sends email to several recipients, it won't break if one of the email addresses would respond with a bounce later. It's like send an go.

If you need more insights on email delivery you can use the Email Logs feature in Slaesforce:

[Email Log Reference](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=email_logs_format.htm&type=5)